# what is the adjoint operator of an integral?!

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration

Let us define 
$$Tf(x,y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y) dx$$

What would be the adjoint operator of $T$?

Comment: You've got $f$ as a function of only $y$ on the left but of $x$ and $y$ on tge right; how does that work?  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis I think OP means that $(Tf)$ is a function of $y$, obtained by "integrating out" the variable $x$ from $f$.

Comment: For this question to make sense we need to know which space $f$ belongs to, and which space $T$ maps to.

Comment: @ rolandcyp $f: R^2 \Rightarrow R$ and $T$ is just intgeral of $f$ over $x$.

Comment: For $T$ to be well defined, $f$ must at least be in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$. Which space will $Tf$ be considered in? The adjoint operator depends (by definition) on the inner product (or possibly norm).

Comment: Let say  both of them are considered in $L^1(R^2)$

Comment: **This question is missing context or other details**: Please provide additional [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/), which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that $T: V \rightarrow W$. Then let $V^*$ and $W^*$ be spaces of distributions on spaces $V$, $W$ respectively.

Then $T^\dagger: W^* \rightarrow V^*$ is an operator such that
$$ (T^\dagger g)(x,y) = g(y) $$

One can check
\begin{align} \langle T^\dagger g | f \rangle &= \int_{\mathbb{R^2}} (T^\dagger g)(x,y) f(x,y) dxdy = \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R^2}} g(y) f(x,y) dxdy = \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(y) \Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,y) dx\Big)dy = \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(y) \,(Tf)(y) dy = \langle g|Tf\rangle\end{align}